# Can you buy chametz from a store whose owner profited from items sold during Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, hametz-sheavar-alav-pesah

The scenario (theoretical):

Mr. Lachmi sells his Zeppolli store to Luigi before Pesach. He tells Luigi that he can use all his ingredients to make Zeppolis or anything else he wants to sell, so long as he leaves the place kosher and puts up a giant sign in front saying that the store is not Kosher for Passover and is run by a non-Jew during the week of Passover, and Jews cannot purchase products during the week. (We avoided the "marit ayin" problem, I think!)

Luigi makes loads of money selling Zeppolis to Gentiles during the week. After Passover, Luigi sells the store back to Mr. Lachmi, and also gives him 30% of the sales he made.

Q - If Mr. Lachmi takes the money, is this considered as if he had owned chometz during Passover? Would the Jewish public be allowed to shop in his bakery, assuming that he is using flour remaining from during Pesach - would this be considered "Chametz She'avar alav HaPesach?" - Chametz that was owned by a Jew during Pesach?

Comment: Why would you think this does qualify as CSAAHP?